# Axis2 web service stub failing

Tags: apache-axis

We have a website written in Java that makes a web service call. Recently, we have noticed that we are recieving a null response from the web service (The endpoint is a 3rd party not maintained by us). 
I've tracked down the point at which our code is failing and it's in our stub. See the code below, the code is failing between the two System.out.println lines.  My problem is that no exception is thrown, so I don't know why the _operationClient.execute(true); fails. Would anyone have any idea how I can go about solving this?

```
    public SuggestXResponseE suggestX(SuggestXE suggestX0)
            throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
        org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext _messageContext = null;
        try {
            org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient _operationClient = _serviceClient.createClient(_operations[0].getName());
            _operationClient.getOptions().setAction("http://www.test.com/service/suggestX");
            _operationClient.getOptions().setExceptionToBeThrownOnSOAPFault(true);


            addPropertyToOperationClient(_operationClient, org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL2Constants.ATTR_WHTTP_QUERY_PARAMETER_SEPARATOR, "&");

            // create a message context
            _messageContext = new org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext();


            // create SOAP envelope with that payload
            org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope env = null;

            env = toEnvelope(getFactory(_operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()),
                    suggestX0,
                    optimizeContent(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.test.com/service",
                    "suggestX")));
            //adding SOAP soap_headers
            _serviceClient.addHeadersToEnvelope(env);
            // set the message context with that soap envelope
            _messageContext.setEnvelope(env);
            // add the message contxt to the operation client
            _operationClient.addMessageContext(_messageContext);

System.out.println("Log message 1");
            //execute the operation client
            _operationClient.execute(true);
System.out.println("Log message 2");

            org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext _returnMessageContext = _operationClient.getMessageContext(
                    org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDLConstants.MESSAGE_LABEL_IN_VALUE);
            org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope _returnEnv = _returnMessageContext.getEnvelope();

            java.lang.Object object = fromOM(
                    _returnEnv.getBody().getFirstElement(),
                    SuggestXResponseE.class,
                    getEnvelopeNamespaces(_returnEnv));

            return (SuggestXResponseE) object;

        } catch (org.apache.axis2.AxisFault f) {
        // Handle exception.
    } 
        finally {
            _messageContext.getTransportOut().getSender().cleanup(_messageContext);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say it's "failing" at that line of code. How is it failing? What are the symptoms?

Comment: "Log message 1" is printed to the log, but "Log message 2" is not printed to the log. If the execute were successful, then ""Log message 2" should appear in the log. Neither ""Log message 2" or the exception message appear in the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Log message 1");
        //execute the operation client
        _operationClient.execute(true);
System.out.println("Log message 2");
```

If you're getting the first log message but not the second one, then one of two things is happening:

1. `System.exit()` is being called somewhere within `_operationClient.execute()`. You'd recognize this by the fact the process exits.
2. More likely, `_operationClient.execute()` is throwing something.

You say it's not throwing an exception, but it could be throwing an [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) or some other kind of [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html). It's not normally advised to catch non-Exception throwables, but you could add some code to do it temporarily:

```
try {
    _operationClient.execute(true);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    log.error(t);
    throw t;
}
```

You might find that you're getting an `OutOfMemoryError` or a `NoClassDefFoundError` because some jar is missing from your deployment, for example.

Comment: Bingo! I found the problem from adding that exception check you suggested. I had two different axiom-dom jar files in my classpath!